# maven: create same artifact with two different packaging/type

Tags: maven, artifacts

I'm using maven to build artifacts for use in a multi-language development (.net, java, native C++).

I'm using the npandy plugin, the native-maven-plugin, and the standard maven java plugins.

I want to create some common library artifacts that are available for all three of these languages,
e.g.

- commonLibrary.dll
- commonLibrary.lib (win)
- commonLibrary.a   (unix)
- commonLibrary.jar

conceptually it is the same artifact, just with a different extension, for use in a different language. I was attempting to use the maven classifier to distinguish them. However, this doesn't quite work.

the pom file for each of these artifact types has to be different by its packaging, hence
the problem. i.e.

- dotnet-library
- lib
- a
- jar

any ideas how I can create all the artifacts, with the same artifact id ?

cheers

Comment: Look at the maven-assembly-plugin.